# $\pi(x)$ asymptotic as integral $1/\log t$

Tags: integration, prime-numbers, asymptotics

From the prime number theorem we know that $\pi(x)\sim x/\log x$, i.e. $\dfrac{\pi(x)\log x}{x}\rightarrow 1$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$.

How can we use that to show that $\pi(x)\sim\int_2^x\dfrac{1}{\log t}dt$? The integral $\dfrac{1}{\log t}$ does not have a closed form, as far as I know.

Comment: As for the question, show that $$\operatorname{Li}(x) = \int_2^x \frac{dt}{\log t} \sim \frac{x}{\log x},$$ for example by splitting the integral at something like $\dfrac{x}{(\log x)^2}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer What do you mean by splitting the integral? Like splitting into the intervals $[2,x/(\log x)^2]$ and $[x/(\log x)^2,x]$? I can't see how that makes it easier to evaluate/estimate things.

Comment: Yes, splitting like that. The first integral is easily estimated as $O\left(\frac{x}{(\log x)^2}\right)$, and the second as $\sim \frac{x}{\log x}$, since the integrand is "nearly constant" $\frac{1}{\log x}$ there.

Comment: @DanielFischer The first integral is fine, but I'm having trouble with the second one. I know the integrand is "nearly constant", but how can I argue formally that it's $\sum\frac{x}{\log x}$?

Comment: The second integral is bounded $$x\left(1 - \frac{1}{(\log x)^2}\right) \cdot \frac{1}{\log x} < \int_{x/(\log x)^2}^x \frac{dt}{\log t} < x\left(1-\frac{1}{(\log x)^2}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{\log x - 2 \log \log x}.$$ Both sides are $$\frac{x}{\log x} + o\left(\frac{x}{\log x}\right).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have it backwards. The Prime Number Theorem shows that $\pi(x) \sim \int_2^x \frac{1}{\log t} dt,$ which is a much better approximation than $\pi(x) \sim \frac{x}{\log x}.$ To get the "standard form" from the first one, just integrate by parts.

To answer Daniel Fischer's comment, see [this part of the wiki article on the PNT.](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s24/sh/1cad055f-7685-457b-b0dd-c5f9dd22aee3/f3c54009fa43c9eb6d2645646ef58160)

Comment: That depends on what proof you read. The common complex analysis proof shows $\pi(x) \sim \dfrac{x}{\log x}$ (via $\vartheta(x)$).

Comment: @DanielFischer you are kidding, right?  notice that the version you mention has a horrible error term whether or not you know the Riemann hypothesis, so I am sure you can prove this theorem, but it is not the prime number theorem.

Comment: [I'm not kidding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem). Yes, you don't get good error bounds. Still, the asymptotic is right, and it is commonly called the prime number theorem.

Comment: @DavidFischer see the edit.

Comment: By the way, my name is not David.

Comment: @DanielFischer Apologies, you would think that mistyping your name would result in your not seeing the comment :)

Comment: Funny mistake :) Anyway, Igor, the part of Wikipedia you quoted doesn't seem to help much with "proving" what I asked for. I'm interested in doing it directly. Is it possible?

Comment: And "the common complex analysis proof" is since about thirty years, Newman's proof, which doesn't give the error bounds. Yes, it is a pity.

Comment: @PJ Miller the point is that the integration by parts shows that the two formulas have the same first term in the asymptotic expansion, by integrating the log integral by parts, but the version of the PNT of $x/\log x$ for is strictly weaker than the log integral form.

Comment: @DanielFischer Actually, I don't know about that (that Newman's proof is the standard proof). I have never read it (despite the fact that my office used to be Don Newman's!), partly because my number theorist friends have pooh-poohed it, so I had read the proof in Davenport's book, which is what you have to understand if you want to work in the field. So, it may be standard in some circles but not others.

Comment: I didn't say "standard". I said "common". The really good thing about Newman's proof is that it's so easy that you can show it to students with not very much background in complex analysis, that's why it's commonly given in complex analysis courses. If you want to do number theory, you need the better result quite often, I'd think.

Comment: @DanielFischer fair enough...